# Laravel 5.4 - Issue with Jobs after move model

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, jobs

I have this error on my console. I use Jobs from Laravel 5.4 and I have move the **Feed Model** in **App\Models\Feed**. Since two days, I have this error because **Laravel** doesn't find the **Feed Model**. I have restart my Jobs with **php artisan queue:restart**.

> [2017-07-13 10:45:33] staging.ERROR:
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class
>   'App\Feed' not found in
>   /home/site_com/http/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers.php:45

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Feed;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class FetchFeeds implements ShouldQueue {
    protected $feed;
    public function __construct(Feed $feed)
    {
        $this->feed = $feed;
    }
}
```

My Feed model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\HybridRelations;

class Feed extends Model
{
    use HybridRelations;

    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    protected $fillable = [
        //
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    ...
}
```

Comment: So you have a `Feed` folder under `Models`? Please post the model as well

Comment: I have edit the first post with the Feed model.

Comment: You likely have old jobs in the queue. Passing Eloquent models to a job gets them serialized, but because you changed the namespace of the model it can't find them anymore. Clear out the queue, or put the model back temporarily to run them.

Comment: I've flushed Redis database already...

Comment: Can you show us where you dispatch the job?

Comment: I dispatch job in a cron task : https://pastebin.com/r8AjTvY9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the Job name, it works.

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan queue:restart` relies on on the cache system to schedule the restart.

If you are using APCu there is a chance that the cache it is not working with cli jobs. In this case the recommendation is to add `apc.enable_cli=1` to your APCu configuration

In any case I will try to do a complete **stop/start** of the queue listener/worker.

Comment: I have already restart the Job with php artisan queue:restart and flush Redis database. It's a new dispatched job...

Comment: instead of a queue:restart please try a complete stop and start of the queue worker/listener like I suggest you

Comment: How I can do this?